# git push stopped working on Amazon Ec2 instance

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2

Have a problem with pushing to github repo from my server on EC2.

Steps I am taking:

1. `git add somefile`   **successful**
2. `git commit -m "sample commit"` **successful**
3. `git push origin master`   **blank**

On the last step, I don't get usual logs of file being pushed, but no error messages either. It just goes

```
[ec2-user@ip****** app]$ git push origin master
[ec2-user@ip*******app]$
```

and no files are being pushed to my repo on github. Where can I get some logs of what's happening there? I couldn't find any push related logs in .git/logs

NOTE: It was working perfectly for me last September, then I switched the other projects, and this repo haven't been touched until now. Haven't changed anything in my git, or ec2 configuration in meantime.

As it stands the question is not the clearest, but I am willing to provide any necessary additional info

EDIT: to Sebastian

```
[ec2-user@ip*** app]$ git push -v origin master
Pushing to https://github.com/*myusername*/*repo*.git
[ec2-user@ip******app]$
```

Comment: Do a `git -v push origin master` and update your question with the output.

Comment: done. but nothing pushed to github

Comment: Are you on EC2 classic or on VPC? Has anything changed in your security groups (and or ACLs)?

Comment: @pquery EC2 classic. I haven't changed anything in security groups

Comment: @Sebastian done. but nothing pushed to github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working again after running regular "sudo yum update"

```
Updated:
  curl.x86_64 0:7.36.0-2.45.amzn1                                               
  ec2-net-utils.noarch 0:0.4-1.21.amzn1                                         
  ec2-utils.noarch 0:0.4-1.21.amzn1                                             
  java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.6.0.0-67.1.13.3.64.amzn1                        
  libcurl.x86_64 0:7.36.0-2.45.amzn1                                            
  libpwquality.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.5.amzn1                                         
  nspr.x86_64 0:4.10.4-1.21.amzn1                                               
  nss.x86_64 0:3.16.0-1.35.amzn1                                                
  nss-softokn.x86_64 0:3.16.0-1.19.amzn1                                        
  nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.16.0-1.19.amzn1                                   
  nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64 0:3.16.0-1.19.amzn1                                 
  nss-sysinit.x86_64 0:3.16.0-1.35.amzn1                                        
  nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.16.0-1.35.amzn1                                          
  nss-util.x86_64 0:3.16.0-1.22.amzn1
```

These are the files updated.

Apologies for bringing zero knowledge to the community